# Is it possible to take a screenshot of your screen from within LiveCode?

Tags: image, livecode

I am looking to have the ability of importing a capture of my screen into my LiveCode application.

I generally use the following key combination on my mac: <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>

then imported the image as a control or referenced the image within an image control.

```
set the fileName of image 1 to "/path/to/image.png"
```

Is there a way to do this directly by script, bypassing the need for these additional steps?

Comment: Please, include the code that you have created when trying to import screen captures. Questions on SO must display some understanding of programming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
on mouseUp
  import snapshot
end mouseUp
```

note that you can also be much more specific with the import command, for example specifying the whole screen, or just one part or object of a stack. Make sure to check out all possibilities of the import snapshot command in the dictionary.

```
on mouseUp
  import snapshot from line 1 of the screenrects
  import snapshot from me
end mouseUp
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the "import snapshot" command for this purpose. The following script allows you to take a snapshot of the whole screen-

```
import snapshot from rect (the screenrect)
```

or if you wish to have the same functionality as cmd + shift-4 then it would simply be:

```
import snapshot
```

This will bring up a small arrow that you drag to capture a specific area of the screen.

Importing snapshot creates a new image object on your stack that will be, by default named a variation of "image id 100*"

A list of ways to capture a snapshot using the "import snapshot" command can be found below. These are taken form the "import snapshot"
dictionary entry-

> To import a snapshot for a portion of a stack you use the form: import
>   snapshot from rect[angle] of window windowID Where windowID is the
>   windowID property of the required stack.
>
> To import a snapshot of a specific (non-stack) object, use the form:
>   import snapshot from rect[angle] of chunk Where chunk is any chunk
>   expression resolving to a control, or any expression evaluating to a
>   control reference.
>
> To import a snapshot of an object that has graphic effects applied to
>   it, use the with effects form: import snapshot from rect[angle] of
>   chunk with effects Where chunk is any chunk expression resolving to a
>   control, or any expression evaluating to a control reference.
>
> To import a snapshot of an object in iOS use the form: import snapshot
>   from [ rectangle rect of ] object
>
> To import a snapshot of the screen in iOS use the form: import
>   snapshot from rectangle rect

Answer (score -1):

```
**You could try this in Python & Linux**

import gtk.gdk

w = gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window()
sz = w.get_size()
print "The size of the window is %d x %d" % sz
pb = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB,False,8,sz[0],sz[1])
pb = pb.get_from_drawable(w,w.get_colormap(),0,0,0,0,sz[0],sz[1])
if (pb != None):
    pb.save("screenshot.png","png")
    print "Screenshot saved to screenshot.png."
else:
    print "Unable to get the screenshot."
```